# How does path search work on Cypher and what types of filtering can be done during expansion?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, variable-length

I'm trying to understand Neo4j's mechanics when dealing with path searches. I studied the query patterns and execution plan operators in the developer manual, but I still have some questions.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from the content I read, and from some posts on Neo4j's blog, I understood that Cypher and Java traversals generally perform depth-first searches, more specifically informed searches, and that variable-length queries fit into it. I also read that shortest path planning uses a breadth-first bidirectional search, and a depth-first search as a fallback.

Is there any way to perform breadth-first searches in Neo4j other than that?
I know the APOC procedures library allows this kind of search through path expanders, but I'm limiting my scope to just the Cypher language for now.

Also, does the variable-length pattern run recursively?
And what kinds of filtering are executed during expansion? I read that functions like ALL normally are checked during expansion, but some are executed later.

The reason for these questions is to see to what extent I would be able to manipulate the data and make complex traversals using only Cypher and what already comes with Neo4j, without external libraries and without having to write procedures through the API.

Forgive me if these questions are trivial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Being a declarative query language Cypher doesnot controls how the underlying engine will search the pattern. So by just specifying a pattern we cannot specify which pattern matching algorithm shall be used for finding patterns. So we cannot perform breath first algorithm with just using Cypher.

For running a variable length pattern recursively we can use kleene star over single edge labels for example :KNOWS* or we can use the or operator in cypher for example :KNOWS|FOLLOWS* in cypher. Essentially this means (KNOWS|FOLLOWS)* in Regular Path Query (RPQ) format. Which is equivalent to (a|b)* in regular expression syntax. We can also have more edge labels such as (a|b|c|....)* in cypher.

We can also specify a varibale length over the pattern as ()-[:KNOWS|FOLLOWS*1..6]->() in cypher.

However we cannot do recursive iterations over a few pattern for example a sub-graph which has a node with one incoming edge and atleast two out going edges from the same node. for example a pattern such as this (a)-[r]->(b)-[s]->(c), (b)-[v]->(d). This is an example of a conjunctive pattern.

Filtering can be is normally performed in the WHERE clause based on the property key value pairs. We can set the labels in the pattern expressed in the MATCH clause so that the underlying engine knows the start node. For example as done in the following query

match (a:Person{name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[r]->(b) return * limit 5